# IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 custom $HOME

Tags: git, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 13.1
I have a linux environment where I'm forced to change $HOME. I've exported it but IDEA still points to the old path. I've defined & exported IDEAS_PROPERTIES to point to a modified idea.properties file. The idea.config|system|plugins|log.path work but I think ${user.home} is still pointing to the old path. One symptom is running git from the IDE will not read the .gitconfig that is in the new home path.

Does anyone know how to get IDEA to use $HOME?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround to move forward.  Since idea uses /usr/bin/git, I created a wrapper that looks up the user's initials based on their ip - $SSH_CLIENT.  In implementing this workaround, I found that idea passes the author/email to git via "--author...". line 5 strips that out and uses what is set in /home/$USER_INITIALS/.gitconfig.  If someone has a better answer, I'm all ears.

```
#!/bin/bash
# /usr/bin/git
USER_INITIALS="$(uilookup $SSH_CLIENT)"
GIT_PARAMETERS="$*"
GIT_PARAMETERS="${GIT_PARAMETERS/--author=*--/--}"
( export HOME="/home/$USER_INITIALS" && /usr/libexec/git-core/git $GIT_PARAMETERS )
```

acornblue